# Justify content block bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this code:

```css
.banner {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="banners mb-4">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div class="banner"></div>
            <div class="banner"></div>
            <div class="banner"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
</section>
```

I need on mobile and tablets display: block these elements `banner` with spacing. How I can do it with flex? Now I get elements on inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on viewport you could use this [d-* classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/display/)

So this

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
```

would be

```
<div class="d-lg-flex justify-content-between">
```

This will make `.banner` block(the default behavior of div) till large viewport

Comment: no need d-block since block is already by default for div element

Answer (score 0):

You can change the direction on small screen (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/flex/#direction)

```css
.banner {
  background: red;
  border:1px solid;
  min-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="banners mb-4">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex  flex-column flex-sm-row justify-content-between">
            <div class="banner col m-2"></div>
            <div class="banner col m-2"></div>
            <div class="banner col m-2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
</section>
```